Error cloning remote repo 'origin' and Could not init /var/jenkins_home/workspace/XX
I have a problem with the connection to the Github repository on Jenkins. Jenkins is running on Docker. My problem is that my created pipeline works at first and in the second build it gives these error messages “ Error cloning remote repo ‘origin’ and Could not init /var/jenkins_home/workspace/XX”. I have to say that the Github repository XX has already been deleted. There is a new Github repository with the name “rp”. I cannot establish a connection to “rp”.
In addition, jenkins does not recognize the path to Git (Git installations, Git, Path to Git executable). When I write “where git” in cmd window, the location appears. But if I type it in “Path to Git executable”, it does not work.
All the applications run on windows.
I therefore ask for suggestions for a solution.
Many thanks in advance!
What i have done yet:
Creating new Repository, Update credentials, search after path to Git, setting environment variables in windows (system)
